# How can I show an activity indicator on a UITabBarController

Tags: ios, xcode, uitabbarcontroller

I have a UITabBarController with multiple nav vcs. How can I show an activity indicator on the current visible vc from the tab bar controller's `viewDidLoad`?

Answer (score 0):

**Objective-C**

```
UIViewController *currentVisibleViewController = [self.tabBarController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:self.tabBarController.selectedIndex];

//Add ActivityIndicator on currentVisibleViewController.view
```

**Swift-3**

```
let currentVisibleViewController = self.tabBarController?.viewControllers?[(self.tabBarController?.selectedIndex)!]
//Add ActivityIndicator on currentVisibleViewController.view
```